# Need a jumpstart with Excel VBA object model

Tags: vba, excel

I don't work with Excel much, and never as a true spreadsheet / calculator. I'm given tabulated text data and format it according to a set of rules. Until now this has been manageable manually but it's grown unwieldy so I thought I'd try to automate it. Then I looked into the Excel object model and... wow.

I have no trouble laying out the logic of the process, but plugging in the correct objects, methods etc is a nightmare. I'd appreciate any help in this regard. Here is the logic / pseudocode:

```
for each cell "x" in a selected range (in a single column)
  if "x" is not blank
    for each cell "y" in selection after current "x"
      if text in "y" = text in "x"
        change format of "y" to right, red ("is a repeat")
        if FG color of "x" is blue
          change format of "x" to left, black ("is repeated")
        end if
      end if
    end if
  next "y"
next "x"
```

I can't even find an object called "cell" in the model...

Comment: open watch window ... add a watch `activesheet`  ... context: all ... expand the tree .... you can also use `activesheet.cells`  or `range("d2")`

Comment: `for each cell "y" in selection after current "x"` What do you mean by this? I just need to make sure where you're comparing `x`.

Comment: MSDN documentation for [Excel's Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-object-excel). **is not blank**: `IsEmpty(cell_x)`. Colours in [Range.Interior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/interior-object-excel). Record macro for some cells you need to achieve, then understand the code it recorded for you.

Comment: x to left and y to right? Is this OFFSET ? If so OFFSET by 1 column? Even if column selected is A and you wrap around to other side of sheet? Example images often help.

Comment: Not sure CELL is displayed in the model but it is a member of the CELLS collection in the RANGE Class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221403(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: @L42 - In a single column, a continuous range of cells is selected. Within that selection, from top to bottom, compare each cell "x" in order, to each subsequent cell ("y"') - those not yet checked. It 'feels' a bit like a bubble sort in that respect.

Comment: @PatricK - thanks for the hints. I suspect that `.Interior` is referring to the background color, where I'm looking for the FG color, but the reference is a start. As for recording a macro, I tried this but I can't do what I want in steps because the 'compare' is purely visual.

Comment: @QHarr - Thanks. I did spend quite some time in the VBA object browser, but since `.Cells` isn't at the top level it means drilling down into each top-level object to find it that way. Knowing what `.Range` is will help a lot.

Comment: There is a search box you can use next to the binoculars symbol. Enter the work CELLS there and then use the drill down functionality and hyperlinks.

Comment: If by FG you mean the foreground  colour of the text, that's tricky because many things can colour text: The Font object's color property; a conditional Format and  a number format off the top of my head - there may be more

Answer (score 1):

'for each cell "x" in a selected range (in a single column)

```
Dim x as Range
For each x in selection
```

if "x" is not blank

```
   if x <> "" then
```

for each cell "y" in selection after current "x"

```
  Dim y as range
  for each y in range(y.address & ":" & cells(selection.row.count,y.column).address)
```

EDIT: Spot the mistake! That should be for each y in Range(X.Offset(1,0).address etc

if text in "y" = text in "x"

```
    If x.text = y.text then
```

change format of "y" to right, red ("is a repeat") 'Don't ask much!

```
    y.NumberFormat = "[Red]" & Chr$(34) & "Is a Repeat" & Chr$(34) & ";[Red]" & Chr$(34) & "Is a Repeat" & Chr$(34) & ";[Red]" & Chr$(34) & "Is a Repeat" & Chr$(34) & ";[Red]" & Chr$(34) & "Is a Repeat" & Chr$(34)
```

End Sub
        y.HorizontalAlignment = xlright

if FG color of "x" is blue

```
    if x.interior.color = vbblue then'or use rgb function
```

change format of "x" to left, black ("is repeated")

```
    x.NumberFormat = Chr$(34) & "Is a Repeat" & Chr$(34) & ";" & Chr$(34) & "Is a Repeat" & Chr$(34) & ";" & Chr$(34) & "Is a Repeat" & Chr$(34) & ";" & Chr$(34) & "Is a Repeat" & Chr$(34)
    x.horizontalalignment = xlright

         end if
       end if
    end if
   next y
 next x
```

Comment: Well thanks, I didn't expect a whole function, just hints. Much appreciated -- I'll try this out to see if it fits. In any case it's at least a great start. And FWIW the "is a repeat" etc are just parenthetical comments, not part of the expected output.

Comment: One of the things I struggled with is how to iterate over the rest of the selection after the current "x". Your `for each y in range(y.address & ":" & cells(selection.row.count,y.column).address)` doesn't seem to do this either. Maybe instead, a way to use a normal `For-Next` loop bounded by the 'next' row --> 'last' row?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to clues provided here, I've managed to do this -- without a deep understanding of how. (-:

I'm sure there are better ways to define the range of "every cell 'below' the current cell in the selection" but this does work (some superfluous stuff removed).

Criticisms welcomed -- it's how I learn.

```
Sub FormatColors()

Dim Outer As Range
Dim Inner As Range
Dim txtColumn As String
Dim RangeEnd As String
Dim txtInner As String

With Selection
  txtColumn = Chr(.Column + 64)  'limited to A-Z
  RangeEnd = ":" & txtColumn & Trim(Str(.Row + .Rows.Count))
  .Font.Color = vbBlue
  .Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
End With

For Each Outer In Selection
  If Not IsEmpty(Outer) Then
    txtInner = txtColumn & Trim(Str(Outer.Row + 1)) & RangeEnd
    For Each Inner In Range(txtInner)
      If Inner.Text = Outer.Text Then
        Inner.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        Inner.Font.Color = vbRed
        If Outer.Font.Color = vbBlue Then
           Outer.HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
           Outer.Font.Color = vbBlack
        End If
      End If
    Next
  End If
Next

End Sub
```